# Accessing Windows Clipboard via non-Focused Application Causing Issues After a Ctrl-C to Copy to Clipboard

Tags: c#, windows, clipboard

I have a background application that activates a **Ctrl-C** (to copy to clipboard) that is then picked up by the application with focus.   The in focus application then does what most applications do and it **copies its data to the clipboard**.   Then my background application upon notification from a **WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE** windows message accesses the clipboard for the data and saves it to a memory location that I can later use to paste.

This works for most applications.

However, I'm finding with "Paint 3D" after selecting an object (a 3D model from their library) and activating Ctrl-C and then getting the data from the clipboard it displays a window with the text "pasting...". It goes a little bonkers for a few seconds, almost like it will crash, though it doesn't.  It's like Paint 3D retains ownership of the clipboard and reacts to me accessing its data.  I'd like to make it not respond to my accessing of the clipboard.

You can see it, because the exact same problem occurs when the free program "InsideClipboard" is running (if you run it, select from the menu: Options->Refresh On Clipboard Change).  Here is where that program can be found: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/inside_clipboard.html.  It's a tiny program that runs right out of the box.  Select an object in Paint 3D and press Ctrl-C to see it.

I've tried various experiments.  One experiment was to send the Ctrl-C, then I manually change focus to another Window (I use a Thread.Sleep(2000) delay for this test), but the problem persists.

It happens when I use IDirectObject.GetData(format).

Here is my C# abbreviated code (the actual code is quite large) that clones the clipboard data:

```
//The clipboard cloning code    
IDirectObject clipboardDataObject;

try
{

    clipboardDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
}
    catch (Exception)
{
    return false;
}

string[] formats = clipboardDataObject.GetFormats();
if(formats.Length == 0)
    return;
    
IDataObject newObj = new DataObject();

foreach (string format in formats)
{            
    object o = clipboardDataObject .GetData(format);
    if (o != null)
    {
        newObj.SetData(format,o);   
    }
}
```

Here is part of the code that activates the copying of the clipboard data

```
 private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == NativeMethods.WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
    {            
        OnClipboardChanged();  // This activates the cloning code above          
    }

    return WndProcSuccess;
}
```

I hope that was clear. If not, I will attempt to explain it better.  Does anyone know what the problem is and how to correct for it?

I'm working in Visual Studio 2019, C#, WPF, on Windows 10.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The clipboard is complicated. An app can fill the clipboard with many different formats. Then, when it's time to read the clipboard, the reading app can interrogate the clipboard and choose what format it likes (or, like Word does with _Paste Special_, let the user pick). The other thing that the first app can do is put a note in the clipboard saying, roughly, you need to get me involved if you read this format. That might be what's going on.

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#processing-the-wm_renderformat-and-wm_renderallformats-messages

Comment: Reading your code again... Are you reading data in every format? Generally, you pick the best one.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman -- Thanks for the link.  I've been studying it.  If I copy from an application, e.g. Paint 3D, and paste into another, is it required that I take ownership of the clipboard?   I've noticed that it works smoothing when I copy from Paint 3D, and then paste in Paint.Net, but when I try to do this with my program by getting the  data out of the clipboard, Paint 3D acts up.   I can't see a way to take ownership without emptying the clipboard according to specs. Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-operations#clipboard-ownership

Comment: @Flydog57 -- I am copying every format to clone the clipboard.  Basically, I want to preserve clipboard contents from a ^C in application A into memory slots in my application, and then be able to select any of the slots to paste again to any other application.  I do this by copying the data back to the clipboard and invoking a ^V.  This has worked for most applications, but some are fighting me.  I'm cloning to preserve everything in tact.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman -- Because I've noticed that to invoke the WM_RENDERFORMAT and WM_RENDERALLFORMATS messages you have to own the clipboard.